# TileMap occupy same physical space independent of screen density?

Tags: android, tile

I have been reading about this lately and I don't really understand how i should manage that my TileMap occupies same physical space independent of screen density.

- Tiles: 48x32 pixels.
- TileMap: 10x10 Tiles.

How can i achieve that in all devices the map occupies exactly 480x320 pixels of the screen? Is this possible?

Do i have to put Tiles of different sizes?

- MDPI: 48x32 pixels.
- HDPI: 72x48 pixels.

And so on?

Trying things is only getting me more confused, please clarify this to me.

Comment: One of the main ideas for the game that i have is that i don't want to use some sort of scrollable function for the map, i want all the map to be visible on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule, you should never deal in px for anything. Always use dp (display pixels), because they automatically scale for the different densities.

Comment: I still fail to understand. I should convert Tile width and height values to DP? What about the bitmaps, i will need different bitmap sizes aswell?

Comment: Yes, check out [this tool](http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/android_dp_px_calculator/) if you need some pointers!